# microtype in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, microtype, kerning, font-expansion

Currently `microtype` package supports only protrusion in XeLaTeX. Is there an option to use other micro-typography features (expansion, kerning, spacing, tracking) in XeLaTeX?

Or should I forget about OpenType fonts and go back to pdfLaTeX?

Comment: Why don't you try `LuaLaTeX`?

Comment: @DG' I tried it just now. It turned out to be toooooo slooooow. I have not enough patience to wait for a minute every time I want to change tracking in a paragraph.

Comment: @pantlmn Spacing and tracking can be achieved by means of the `fontspec` package.

Comment: lualatex isn't so much slower than xelatex on my system. Perhaps you have this problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234785/2388

Comment: @HenriMenke: ...and probably it's a good idea to forget about font expansion ;-)