# Why those latex editors with real-time preview are so slow in rendering previews?

Tags: compiling, preview, live-preview

Merely adding two letters will take a few seconds for editors such as OVerleaf/Sharelatex to render a preview. How could this be the case? I just need a draft preview.

Are there any latex editors that run faster in previewing?

---

PS: high-end core i7

Comment: What matters is the total document length - not how different that length is to its previous length. It has to recompile the lot. Your processor is irrelevant if you're using OverLeaf/ShareLaTeX as your machine isn't doing the compiling. So you can just as soon use a Pentium 486 if you can persuade it to run a sufficiently modern browser to support the web interface. It won't affect compilation time.

Comment: If you compile locally, it will be faster. OverLeaf is very slow. (Don't know about ShareLaTeX.) It doesn't matter which editor you use. The editor has nothing to do with the compilation time, either.

Comment: @cfr How may I compile locally, then?

Comment: Install a TeX distribution.

Comment: Local compilation means you do everything on your PC. With editors such as WinEdt, TexMaker or Lyx. Lyx can provide a WYSIWYG look but it is not perfect. Kile v3 beta also can do it. But WYSIWYG requires compilation of whole document as @cfr suggested;, not local part of it.

Comment: If you are a Win 10 x64 user, I recommend MikTex as the TeX distribution. I also suggest to use LyX along with TexMaker or TexStudio. If your document is long , it is always going to take long times once you compile it. You should structure your code to compile sections, not the whole document.

Comment: It also depends on the LaTeX engine. For example LuaLaTex runs faster than PdfLaTex in general.

Comment: Also there is no such thing as "draft preview" in TeX/LaTeX. Usual process is to use a regular text editor with some color coding to write the LaTeX .tex extension file , then compile with LaTeX or pdfLaTeX, then preview dvi, ps or pdf files with Yap, GhostView (or PsView) or SumatraPDF (or Adobe Reader or PDFXchange).

Comment: @BarisErkus »LuaLaTex runs faster than PdfLaTex«  That is absolutely [not true](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234757)!

Comment: @BarisErkus  MikTeX isn't the only thing to use on Windows, i prefer TeX Live. Also, using LyX is different from using normal LaTeX. Using dvi or ps for previewing isn't really a modern approach as well.

Comment: @Johan You are right. In the world of LaTeX, there are many ways  of doing the same thing. For beginners and for researchers who  does not have many colleagues with tex-expertise, like myself, it is sometimes almost compulsory to pick a method that gives you the quickest results. MikTex was easier for me especially for Windows. You are also right about LyX, dvi and ps. I know direct pdf is the way to go nowadays and LuaTex is becoming more popular. On the otherhand, if you are a starter and read many tutorials available on the net, they will lead you to more traditional methods with dvi and ps

Comment: @BarisErkus Many resources now assume direct  PDF compilation. Most editors use pdfTeX by default. MikTeX has certain issues which do not affect TeX Live. (The reverse may be true, too.) For example, installation of font packages seems to be more reliable, it is a better choice if you want to compile off line and so on. But it is true that MikTeX is designed for Windows in a way that TL is not. I definitely wouldn't recommend LyX, though. And pdfTeX is definitely faster than XeTeX or LuaTeX. (In general.)

Comment: @cfr: Why would you not recommend Lyx?  Just because its high-level approach? Are you using regular text-editors? If so which one?

Comment: @berkus Actually, I should have said: I wouldn't recommend LyX to a beginner. It hides things away, including warnings and errors, and makes it more difficult to apply solutions from standard sources. Sooner or later --- usually sooner --- people need to use the lower level. If you have been using LyX, that's alien territory. Basically, it adds layers of complexity which I think it is easier to do without in the beginning. Worse, the layers of complexity are hidden by layers which make the complexity look simpler. It looks easier. But it isn't.

Comment: @cfr agreed. When I thought of the past, I remembet I was also using mostly text editors. For some reason, I am attracted by LyX.

Comment: @berkus I'm not attracted. But I can see the appeal and I think it is great people have this option, once they have a bit of experience and understand what to do when things go wrong etc.

Comment: @Henri I had the impression from some of my previous tests that LuaLaTeX runs faster. Maybe I am confused? Brief elaboration why its slow? A post may be?